# Popup when Activity starts Android

Tags: android, popup

I have a view without a `Fragment` unfortunately. Now I need to show a `PopupWindow` when the activity starts. To show the popup window, the entire view must be loaded. In a fragment, the popup would be shown in `onViewCreated`.

Now since I do not have a Fragment and it would take some time to redo everything, is it possible to show the popup when the activity starts?

I have seen suggestions like:

```
private void loadingPopup() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog, null);

    final PopupWindow windows = new PopupWindow(layout , 300,300,true);
    windows.setFocusable(false);
    windows.setTouchable(true); 
    windows.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    layout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            windows.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

When I try it, no popup is shown. By the way, is this solution really 100 % safe? I do not see how the runnable would know when the view is actually complete?

Comment: You need to `post()` that `Runnable` on a `View` in the `Activity`'s hierarchy, not on the `PopupWindow`'s own `View`.

Comment: Ok, but why does it help to just use a runnable? Is it automatically not called until the view is ready?

Comment: `PopupWindow` needs a `View` in the the `Activity` to know where to place itself; either an anchor `View` for dropdown style, or a `View` just to know how to position itself based on the `View`'s dimensions and location, along with the `Gravity` you pass. In either case, those `View`s need to be laid out already for it to get usable values. When an `Activity` starts up, its `View`s aren't actually laid out until some time after `onCreate()`, so you need to delay the `PopopWindow` a bit, which is what the `post()` accomplishes.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, the first argument in the `showAtLocation()` call needs to be a parent `View` in the `Activity`, not the `PopupWindow`. You can use that same parent `View` for the `post()` call.

Comment: Yes, I understand the post makes a delay. But is the delay guaranteed to be sufficiently long? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, the `post()` is putting that `Runnable` into a message queue, and if you `post()` to a `View` that's been attached to the `Activity`'s hierarchy, the `Runnable` won't execute until after the `View`'s layout.